# Trouble with BackGround

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've problems with an image, I've create a background for my application called gridBg.png and I've read it in this way:

```
        string currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        if (File.Exists((currentDir + @"/Images/gridBg.png")))
        {
            bgAnimated.StopAnimation();
            bgAnimated.GifSource = currentDir + @"/Images/gridBg.png";
            bgAnimated.NormalLoopFrameCount = 20;
            bgAnimated.SpecialLoopFrameCount = 20;
            bgAnimated.TotalLoopFrameCount = 40;
            bgAnimated.NormalLoopRepeatCount = 1;
            bgAnimated.SpecialLoopRepeatCount = 1;
            bgAnimated.StartAnimation();
        }
```

On debug mode it works all properly. I've add the image on the setup project and I've given to it Images path. When I install and try the application it works properly too but the problem is that some of my friends does not see the image but the image is on the right place, the Images folder. Anyone has suggests?

**SOLVED: string currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);**

Comment: What do you mean by `image is on the right place`? Are images being displayed but with different coordinates? or are they not even being displayed?

Comment: @Shaharyar, if you read his question - there is no image on his friends' machine.

Comment: @Moo-Juice You are right! little bit misunderstanding.

Comment: @Shaharyar I was trying to say that the image isn't dispalyed but it is on the folder Images.

Comment: Since this is Windows Forms, you can use [Application.ExecutablePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx). As in `Path.GetDirectory(Application.ExecutablePath)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can even think this could happen is the `Working Directory` for your friends isn't set to the install directory. This would cause the `currentDir` to be wrong.

Per the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx), `GetCurrentDirectory` does this:

> Gets the current **working directory** of the application

Comment: +1, my thoughts exactly.  Perhaps `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` is in order?

Comment: @Moo-Juice, that is one possible workaround. I would wonder, how did the `Working Directory` even get set wrong? Maybe something wrong with their shortcut?

Comment: Not sure as we don't have access/information to the OPs friends computer.  But if ever I am referencing some resource, relative to my executable, I always use the executing location so I don't have to worry about this scenario.

Comment: @Moo-Juice with Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location I obtain the name of the executable, in my case Dashboard.exe

Comment: @user2569789, you could then easily use `Path.GetDirectoryName` against that path.

Comment: An alternative is `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

Comment: Now I'm trying in this way:
string currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
I will make my friends install the application and report the result to you!

Comment: @user2569789, sounds great, and I look forward to a positive report!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I'm new, how can I do it??

Comment: @ThomasSquall, right under the voting control is a transparent check mark. Click that check mark and it will turn green.